# Android: When onStartCommand is finished, onDestroy isn't created

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Can anyone help. I have built a service that executes with the BOOT_COMPLETED intent, hence my service is started when the device is booted.
n
In my onStartCommand i am registering the service with the AlarmManger to execute every 15 minutes.

This works but i notice that my service is never stopped hence when onStartCommand finished - it never stops, the onDestroy is NEVER called.

I need to return an integer from onStartCommand which i believe controls the life time..

What integer should i return?

What am i doing wrong?

Thank in advance

**EDIT**

Currently the serive returns super.onStartCommand(......

which is by default. So what is being returned here?

And if i remove it should i not call (rather than return) to super.onStartCommand on the first line on my onStartCommand in my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK document of [Service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) say that

> The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called

For the return value of `onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`, the document says that

> The return value indicates what semantics the system should use for the service's current started state. It may be one of the constants associated with the START_CONTINUATION_MASK bits.

and

> public static final int START_CONTINUATION_MASK
>   Since: API Level 5
>
> Bits returned by onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) describing how to continue the service if it is killed. May be START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY, START_REDELIVER_INTENT, or START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

So, if you want to stop your service, you should call `Context.stopService()` or `Service.stopSelf()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `onStartCommand()`, it only passes **intent** to your already created service. It is not supposed to kill itself after the method is executed.

To kill your service, use `stopSelf()` and then it will call `onDestroy()` method of your service.

You may return any of the following value depending on your requirements in onStartCommand:

- START_CONTINUATION_MASK
- START_FLAG_REDELIVERY
- START_FLAG_RETRY
- START_NOT_STICKY
- START_REDELIVER_INTENT
- START_STICKY
- START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY

For more info, read Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) carefully.